# Could not create a table | oracle | Missing right parenthesis error

Tags: oracle

Here is the DDL command:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(
      student_id int(11) CONSTRAINT st_id_pk PRIMARY KEY, 
      name varchar2(50) CONSTRAINT st_na_uq NOT NULL UNIQUE,
      address varchar2(100) CONSTRAINT st_ad_de DEFAULT 'cornelia',
      class_id int(11) CONSTRAINT st_cl_fk REFERENCES CLASS(student_id),
      section varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
      age int(11) DEFAULT '16', 
      CHECK (age >= 15)
);
```

Comment: Just being curious - what is column AGE supposed to contain? If that's age of a student whose data you're storing in this table, then that's a pretty much useless information. It would show how old was that student at the time of insert, but - what would be its purpose several years later? Why not storing date of birth instead? That seems to be better information.

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

- `int` should [not be followed](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLQR/sqlqr06001.htm#SQLQR954) by a precision argument. Either do `int` or `number(11)`, but not `int(11)`.
- `DEFAULT` is not something that can be specified as a `CONSTRAINT`. Leave out `CONSTRAINT`

This will work (provided that the reference to `CLASS(student_id)` is correct):

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT(
      student_id int CONSTRAINT st_id_pk PRIMARY KEY, 
      name varchar2(50) CONSTRAINT st_na_uq NOT NULL UNIQUE,
      address varchar2(100) DEFAULT 'cornelia',
      class_id int CONSTRAINT st_cl_fk REFERENCES CLASS(student_id),
      section varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
      age int DEFAULT 16, 
      CHECK(age>=15)
);
```